# MVC implementation in kobold2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I am noob in kobold2d  but familiar with cocos2d now  i have installed kobold2d  but problem is that  I don't know how i get KTViewController, KTModel and all other Kobold touch classes .

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

KoboldTouch is a separate commercial product [available here](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/koboldtouch/).

Comment: I am confused about kobold2d and kobold touch